# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches for custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, routes

So I created a small model/controller to handle tokens in my app, with a custom route. However when I ran the tests (rspec) I would get a failure with

## Relevant code

**controller**

reads the token (generated elsewhere)

```
class TokensController < ApplicationController
  def read_token
    #do whatever this token is supposed to do (unsubscribe, confirm email, etc)
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end
```

**routes**

```
get '/ta/:uuid' => 'tokens#read_token', param: :uuid, as: 'token_action'
```

*rake routes produces*

```
token_action GET    /ta/:uuid(.:format)    tokens#read_token {:param=>:uuid}
```

**model**

Included to show that the token is using uuid when creating the link, not the id

```
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    uuid
  end    
end
```

And it worked in development mode! :D

But when I ran the tests…

## Test

**rspec controller test**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TokensController, type: :controller do
  describe "#index" do
    it "test" do
      get :read_token, uuid: "12345" #12345 is obviously not real
      expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end
end
```

## Error Message

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: 
    No route matches` {:action=>"read_token", :controller=>"tokens", :uuid=>"12345"}
```

## What I tried

Well… pretty much everything.

- I wrote the route with every way I could
- I changed `:uuid` to `:id` thinking that may be the issue
- I tried specifying the attributes in different ways, to no avail
- I tried every solution to similar issues on stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can** make this work by adding `use_route: :controller_name` to make it work;

```
get :index, uuid: "12345", use_route: :tokens
```

but that I was getting this error was confusing and code smell.

## Final Solution

However, the better solution would be to use the proper rails route resource (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

```
resource :vendor_registration, only: [], path: '/' do
  get :read_token, on: :member, path: '/ta/:uuid'
end
```

and it now works; and still uses the same path

Answer (score -1):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tokens, path: "token", only: [:create] #-> POST url.com/token

#app/controllers/tokens_controller.rb
class TokensController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @token = Token.create
      redirect_to root_url if @token
   end
end

#app/models/token.rb
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_token :uuid
end
```

[`has_secure_token`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html) handles `UUID` / token generation through `ActiveRecord`, so no need to manually set it through the routes (massive security benefits).

--

To test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe TokensController, type: :controller do
  describe "#create" do
    it "has_token" do
      post :create, use_route: :tokens
      assigns(:token).should_not be_nil
      expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not very experienced with tests (should change this year); hopefully you can see the benefits of setting the `uuid` through the backend, rather than routes.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. I am not setting a token, I am reading it. The token is set in the backend with (currenly with `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.to_s` but I am going to look into `has_secure_token`)

Comment: The :index controller simply reads the token. The code above is *extremely* pared down to show the rspec controller error more than the token functionality

Comment: Okay I misunderstood your reasoning etc. Still doesn't negate that your pattern isn't that good.

Comment: Pattern being the way the routes is written or the rspec test? What is it that is wrong pattern?

Comment: Pattern being how efficient the solution is